# Как склеить 3 текстовых файла с помощью awk с переборами текстов

Tags: awk, keyword

Есть 3 файла txt, в каждом файле в каждой строке слово или словосочетание.

Как с помощью paste и awk соединить 3 файла или столбца с перебором всех строк.

Необходимоcть на аналог PPC keyword generator слишком медленно после миллиона генерирует. f1,f2,f3 - txt файлы. разделитель строки через paste -d \n кажется должен быть
результирующий файл хотелось бы видеть по след алгоритму:
 f1

```
Acapella Audio
Acoustic Smart
```

f2

```
австралийские
австралия
Америка
```

f3

```
Round Grille
Square Grille
гриль
Защитная решетка
```

result

```
Acapella Audio Arts австралийские Round Grille
Acapella Audio Arts австралийские Square Grille
Acapella Audio Arts австралийские гриль
Acapella Audio Arts австралийские Защитная решетка
Acapella Audio Arts австралия Round Grille
Acapella Audio Arts австралия Square Grille
Acapella Audio Arts австралия гриль
Acapella Audio Arts австралия Защитная решетка
Acapella Audio Arts Америка Round Grille
Acapella Audio Arts Америка Square Grille
Acapella Audio Arts Америка гриль
Acapella Audio Arts Америка Защитная решетка
Acoustic Smart австралийские Round Grille
Acoustic Smart австралийские Square Grille
Acoustic Smart австралийские гриль
Acoustic Smart австралийские Защитная решетка
Acoustic Smart австралия Round Grille
Acoustic Smart австралия Square Grille
Acoustic Smart австралия гриль
Acoustic Smart австралия Защитная решетка
Acoustic Smart Америка Round Grille
Acoustic Smart Америка Square Grille
Acoustic Smart Америка гриль
Acoustic Smart Америка Защитная решетка
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: С запросами готовых решений нужно куда нить на http://freelansim.ru/ там быстро всё сделают. А то нет ни строчки кода, соображений что как делалось и что не работает. Как ТЗ - нормально.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо сделать два вложенных цикла. После каждого файл необходимо закрывать, чтобы потом вновь начать читать его сначала.

```
awk '{ 
       while ((getline line2 < "f2") > 0){
         while ((getline line3 < "f3") > 0){
            print $0 " " line2 " " line3
         }
         close("f3")
       }
       close("f2")
     }' f1 > result
```